# How to work with 2 lists at the same time in haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to solve an exercise in haskell about alphabets. Given a list of words in a new alphabetical order, find this new alphabet.

For example, given the words `["ab","abd","abc","ba","bd","cc"]`,
the new possible alphabets are `"abdc"` or `"adbc"`.

I started by computing all possible alphabetical orders

```
alfabet :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [[a]]
alfabet list = permutations $ nub $ concat $ list
```

After this, I think I should filter out those alphabets that are wrong, but I can't seem to pass along enough info. I've tried using the built-in `filter` function, I've tried to write my own sort function so that when I sort the words by the new order, the resulting list is the same as the input list thus the alphabet is correct. All to no avail.

I guess the biggest problem I have is that I need to be able to work with two lists (the words and the different alphabets) at the same time and loop over them in a different way.

Any tips or help? Thanks

Comment: Can you post any code that you have, no matter how imperfect?

Comment: The number of `premutations` grows as the factorial of N, faster than exp!  Just enumerating possibilities for a 26 char alphabet would take `fact 26 ~= 4*10^26`.  If you could create one per CPU cycle (wildly optomistic), it would still take over a billion years on a 10 core GHz machine.  If this is OK (ie- N will be restricted very small), I could help you with the algorithm you have started, else you might want to consider another approach, let us know, and we can help with that.  (Try `length $ permutation "abcd"` for varying string sizes for reference).

Comment: The problem was limited to alphabets of 4 or 5 letters so computational power wouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's more than one way to approach this. Your suggested way is to generate all possible alphabets on the letters you have, then filter them out by which ones are consistent with the example data. I'll show you a way of doing that first.

Another way would be to distill the information from the example data into some information about what order the letters can come in (mathematicians call this a partial ordering), then extend that into all the possible orderings.

## Approach 1: Filtering all the possible alphabets

```
import Data.List (permutations, nub, sort)
```

### Sorting

I'll use a type synonym `Alphabet` to make clearer which lists are potential alphabets and which are words, and define an ordering based on an alphabet (`byAlphabet`), and extend it to apply to a list by `lexiographic` ordering.

```
type Alphabet a = [a]

byAlphabet :: Eq a => Alphabet a -> a -> a -> Ordering
byAlphabet alphabet x y 
    | x == y = EQ 
    | otherwise = if y `elem` (dropWhile (/=x) alphabet) then LT else GT

lexiographic :: (a->a->Ordering) -> [a]->[a]->Ordering
lexiographic cmp [] [] = EQ
lexiographic cmp [] _ = LT
lexiographic cmp _ [] = GT
lexiographic cmp (x:xs) (y:ys) = case cmp x y of
    EQ -> lexiographic cmp xs ys
    x -> x
```

### Checking against the example data

We need to check whether a given list of words is `consistentWith` the given data:

```
consistentWith :: Eq a => [[a]] -> Alphabet a -> Bool
consistentWith xss alphabet = all (/=GT) $ 
       zipWith (lexiographic $ byAlphabet alphabet) xss (tail xss)
```

You seemed to be struggling with using that across a list of potential alphabets, but did know you can use `filter`:

```
anyOKby :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [Alphabet a] -> [Alphabet a]
anyOKby sortedWords = filter (consistentWith sortedWords)
```

### Solution

Giving a slightly edited `alfabet` function, which filters out ones that don't work.

```
alfabet :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [Alphabet a]
alfabet list = anyOKby list $ permutations $ nub $ concat $ list

example = ["ab","abd","abc","ba","bd","cc"]
```

This works as expected:

```
ghci> byAlphabet "abc" 'c' 'a'
GT
ghci> lexiographic (byAlphabet "abc") "ccba" "ccbc"
LT
ghci> consistentWith example "abcd"
False
ghci> consistentWith example "abdc"
True
ghci> alfabet example
["abdc","adbc"]
```

Now that's a rather slow way because it generates many many potential alphabets then slowly filters them out. The first time I tried, I gave up waiting for `alfabet (sort $ words "hello there the their he and at ah eh")` to print.

---

## Approach 2: find a partial ordering and extend it

I'll use a data type to show which characters are before which others, so `'a' :<: 'b'` would represent that `'a'` has to be before `'b'` in the alphabet

```
data CMP a = a :<: a deriving (Eq,Show)
```

### Comparison facts from example data

I'm going to use `[CMP a]` instead of `Maybe (CMP a)` just because it's easier to `concat` than to `import Data.Maybe (catMaybes)`, but each adjacent pair of words can give at most one comparison `fact` about the alphabet. The `facts` functions use the nice `zipWith f xs (tail xs)` trick to use `f` to make one thing from each adjacent pair in a list.

```
justTheFirst :: [a] -> [a]
justTheFirst [] = []
justTheFirst (a:_) = [a]

fact :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [CMP a]
fact xs ys = justTheFirst . filter neq $ zipWith (:<:) xs ys where
   neq (a:<:b) = a /= b

facts :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [CMP a]
facts xss = nub . concat $ zipWith fact xss (tail xss)
```

**Examples:**

```
ghci> fact "wellbeing" "wellington"
['b' :<: 'i']
*Main ghci> facts example
['d' :<: 'c','a' :<: 'b','a' :<: 'd','b' :<: 'c']
```

### Partial Ordering

We'll use a data type to represent a partial ordering - a list of characters and a set of comparisons, and we'll use the `facts` function to generate the comparisons from sample sorted words, and your `nub.concat` trick to get the letters themselves:

```
data Partial a = Partial {chars :: [a], order :: [CMP a]} deriving Show

partial :: Eq a => [[a]] -> Partial a
partial xss = Partial {chars = nub $ concat xss, order = facts xss}
```

**Example:**

```
ghci> partial example
Partial{chars = "abdc",order = ['d' :<: 'c','a' :<: 'b','a' :<: 'd','b' :<: 'c']}
```

### Potential smallest elements

To grow a list of possible alphabets from a partial ordering, we first need to find which elements can go at the front. It's OK to be at the front as long as you're not bigger than anything, so let's make a list of `nonBigs`. If we put the potential first letter at the front of the alphabet, we can `remove` it from the remaining partial order:

```
nonBigs :: Eq a => [CMP a] -> [a] -> [a]
nonBigs lts as = filter (not.big) as where
   big a = a `elem` (map (\ (_ :<: a) -> a) lts)

remove :: Eq a => a -> [CMP a] -> [CMP a]
remove a = filter no_a where
   no_a (x :<: y) = not $ a `elem` [x,y]
```

**Examples:** (the only thing that's not bigger than something in the example is `'a'`, and there are two facts that don't feature `'a'`)

```
ghci> facts example
['d' :<: 'c','a' :<: 'b','a' :<: 'd','b' :<: 'c']
ghci> nonBigs (facts example) "abcd"
"a"
ghci> remove 'a' (facts example)
['d' :<: 'c','b' :<: 'c']
```

Let's pair up the nonBigs with the partial ordering with that letter removed to get all the possible minimal elements and how to carry on from there:

```
minima :: Eq a => Partial a -> [(a,Partial a)]
minima (Partial as lts) = 
   [(a,Partial (filter (/=a) as) (remove a lts) )|a <- nonBigs lts as]
```

**Example:** You have to have `'a'` first in the example, but after that you could either have `'b'` or `'d'`:

```
ghci> minima $ partial example
         [('a',Partial {chars = "bdc", order = ['d' :<: 'c','b' :<: 'c']})]
ghci> minima $ Partial {chars = "bdc", order = ['d' :<: 'c','b' :<: 'c']}
         [('b',Partial {chars = "dc", order = ['d' :<: 'c']}),
          ('d',Partial {chars = "bc", order = ['b' :<: 'c']})]
```

### Solution

The complicated bit is growing all the possible treelike paths using the "directed graph" that the partial ordering gives. We'll use a tree growing function `f :: input -> [(output,input)]` that tells you all the possible ways to carry on. If that doesn't give you any answers we need `[[]]`, a single empty path, which we'll grow recursively by putting possible first elements in front (`map (o:)`) of each possibility (`treePaths f i'`):

```
treePaths :: (input -> [(output,input)]) -> input -> [[output]]
treePaths f i = case f i of 
   [] -> [[]]
   pairs -> concat [map (o:) (treePaths f i') | (o,i') <- pairs]

alphabets list = treePaths minima (partial list)
```

**Example:** The `alphabets` length calculation is allmost instant, but the `alfabet` length calculation takes more than 2 minutes on my (rather old) laptop; It's quicker to only generate the output you want than to generate every output and discard.

```
ghci> alphabets example
["abdc","adbc"]

ghci> length $ alphabets (sort $ words "hello there the their he and at ah eh")
15120
ghci> length $ alfabet (sort $ words "hello there the their he and at ah eh")
15120
```

Comment: The first approach is exactly what I'm looking for, the problem is limited to short alphabets of 4 or 5 letters so computation time is not an issue

Comment: I can see now the biggest problem I have is I think in "normal" programming language terms of passing along a list to work on. I didn't know it was possible to use filter in the way you just showed

Answer (score 1):

If you were to take `\ls -> map head $ group $ map head ls` and use it on your `["ab","abd","abc",ba","bd",cc"]` that would give you `"abc"`. If you were to repeat a similar procedure for second symbol, where first symbol is the same, you'd also have `"b"`, `"ad"` and `"c"`. These partial alphabets are enough to figure out all possible full alphabets.

I'd suggest using all partial alphabets to build a list (set) of pairs, such that if `('a', 'b')` is in the list, then `'a'` goes before `'b'`. Then insert the symbols one by one into all possible places, using the set as a comparator. Make sure to think about indeterminate orderings.